# Form Submit to Data Extension then send confirmation email with form data

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, triggered-send

New to SFMC and trying to send an form notification with the form data to a hard-coded email.I tried following some of the comments to do this and I must be missing something. Is there a tutorial or documentation on how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a triggered send and include the ampscript in your form processing (or confirmation) page, with the recipient email hardcoded and form fields added as variables. You can adjust this script for your needs: https://etsalesforce.wordpress.com/triggered/